# Example of a metric of the form $ds^2 = g_{vv}(v,x)dv^2+2g_{vx}(v,x)dv\,dx+r^2(v,x)d\Omega^2$ with trapped region

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

Is there a known example of a spherically symmetric metric, especially one describing a spacetime containing trapped region/black hole, which takes the form
$$ds^2 = g_{vv}(v,x)dv^2+2g_{vx}(v,x)dv\,dx+r^2(v,x)d\Omega^2$$
where both $v,x$ are null coordinates and both $g_{vv}$, $g_{vx}$ are not zero? To be precise, $g_{vx}$ is nonzero and $g_{vv}$ can vanish finitely many times but not identically zero function.

On the one hand, the closest I have seen is that of Kruskal coordinates, but it has $g_{vv}=0$. The Vaidja metric on the other hand comes very close, but $x$ in Vaidja spacetime is not a null coordinate (it corresponds to some radial coordinate). This latter case is similar to the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates for Schwarzschild spacetime where we simply set the Vaidja mass function $M(v)=M$.

**UPDATE:** I kept having the doubt that $x$ can be a null coordinate, since it seems to me that a null/lightlike coordinate would require that $g^{xx}=0$. However, the vector $\mathbf{k}:=-\partial_x$ is a null vector, as you can verify, which suggests that the vector field along a null coordinate should be a null vector. Yet in this case $g^{xx}\neq 0$. This should be related to this post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439190/) but I am not sure if I fully understand this. For example, in Vaidja case where $x=r$, I don't think $\partial_r$ is a null vector according to the requirement $g^{rr}=0$.

Comment: If $v$ is a null coordinate you should have $g_{v v} = \partial_v \cdot \partial_v = 0$ by definition of null vector. As $g_{x x} = \partial_x \cdot \partial_x = 0$ in your metric, $x$ is a null coordinate.

Comment: No I don't think that's correct. For Vaidja spacetime, $g_{vv}\neq 0$ but $v$ is null coordinate. The problem is that it's the inverse (contravariant) metric that controls whether the coordinate is null or not, not the (covariant) metric.

Comment: I disagree. The covariant components of the metric tensor are the dot product of the coordinates basis vectors $\partial_\mu$. Please check in a general relativity textbook.

Comment: According to your definition, the standard Eddington-Finkelstein coordinate $v$ would not be null, since $g_{vv}=-(1-2M/r)$ (see any textbook or Wikipedia) while $r$ would a null coordinate ($g_{rr}=0$).

Comment: You may have a metric with the Eddington-Finkelstein infalling radial coordinate $v$ and the Schwarzschild radial coordinate $r$. In this metric $v$ is not a null coordinate, while $r$ is. Instead in a metric with $v$ and the outgoing radial coordinate $u$, both are null coordinates.